# how to solve xilinx-gcc compile c-asm error

Tags: embedded-linux

```
asm volatile (
    "NEONCopyPLD: \n"
    "sub %[dst], %[dst], #64 \n"
    "1: \n"
    "ldnp q0, q1, [%[src]] \n"
    "ldnp q2, q3, [%[src], #32] \n"
    "add %[dst], %[dst], #64 \n"
    "subs %[sz], %[sz], #64 \n"
    "add %[src], %[src], #64 \n"
    "stnp q0, q1, [%[dst]] \n"
    "stnp q2, q3, [%[dst], #32] \n"
    "b.gt 1b \n"
    : [dst]"+r"(dst), [src]"+r"(src), [sz]"+r"(sz) : : "d0", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "d6", "d7", "cc", "memory");
```

{standard input}:634: Error: symbol `NEONCopyPLD' is already defined {standard input}:678: Error: symbol` NEONCopyPLD' is already defined
when compile this code use gcc, gcc shows a error. I cannot find some solution by google, could someone know how to solve this error?

Comment: Can you please extract and provide a [mcve], including instructions how to compile it? Also, it's probably best to add a laguage tag to your question. Also make sure you do some research what the error means, chances are you could solve this riddle yourself. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: aarch64-xilinx-linux-gcc  -mcpu=cortex-a72.cortex-a53 -march=armv8-a+crc -fstack-protector-strong  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/opt/petalinux/2021.2/sysroots/cortexa72-cortexa53-xilinx-linux -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.    $(pkg-config --cflags  vcu-gst-lib vcu-apm-lib) -I./include -O3 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types  -Wall -DPLATFORM_ZCU106 -DHAVE_NEON=1  -c -o ./src/K388_Run-K388_Kfifo.o `test -f './src/K388_Kfifo.c' || echo './'`./src/K388_Kfifo.c

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that it becomes a single, coherent problem description.